# rsync link-destination remote server

Tags: rsync

I have a folder on a local machine and want to rsync to a folder on a remote machine. I would like to evaluate the copy against a folder on the remote machine `--link-dest`. The target directory will then be hardlinked to the `link--destination` folder.

I keep getting `no such file or directory` errors:

```
rysnc -avh -e `ssh -p 2346` --link-dest=user@remote:home/user/techapps/backup user@remote:/home/user/techapps/target
```

Is this possible to do ? or am I just writing it wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When specifying the `--link-dest` option for a destination that is on a remote host, your path should be given as a relative path from the perspective of the destination path.  Don't use the `user@host:full` path syntax.

Of course since the goal is for hard links, it is obviously required for the destination path, and the link-dest path to both exist on the same filesystem.

> --link-dest=DIR
>
> ...
>
> If DIR is a relative path, it is  relative  to  the  destination directory.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response - still having problems should I put the link-dest as ../backup ? The destination and link-destination are in the same folder on the remote machine - the source is on local - tried lots of combinations but keeps saying linkdest no such file or directory (2)

Comment: What do you mean the link-dest and destination are the same folder?  That doesn't make any sense?

Comment: Think I got it - those back ticks were messing it up - it works now but the hardlinks dont seem to be there ie the files in the linkdest folder dont state that there is 2  only 1 same in the destination

Comment: Got it !  Two days :)  Never did the initial backup - hardlinks working.

Comment: You should post what you had to do to solve your problem if it fixing it wasn't related to my answer.

Comment: Ok the relative path part worked  ie --link-dest=../full and the rest was double quotes on the "ssh -p 2346"  not back ticks. The hardlinks weren't present because I was concentrating too hard on getting --link-dest working that I never did an initial back from source to link dest folder. Sorry never used this site before but thanks again the relative path suggestion sorted it

Comment: The relevant bit is not to use the user@host: syntax. Absolute paths seem to work just as well as relative paths. --link-dest=/home/user/techapps/backup should be fine

Comment: @Dom - I see, so you're saying that absolute or relative, it should be `--link-dest=<local_path_on_remote_machine>`, yes?

Answer (score 2):

Ok the relative path part worked ie --link-dest=../full and the rest was double quotes on the "ssh -p 2346" not back ticks. The hardlinks weren't present because I was concentrating too hard on getting --link-dest working that I never did an initial back from source to link dest folder. Sorry never used this site before but thanks again the relative path suggestion sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

*Relative path* in the rsync doc is a bit ambiguous in this context.  `DIR` *with respect to* destination directory, i.e. `DIR` just has to exist on the remote destination, and can be absolute or relative to the destination directory.